# JQuery MouseUp Triggering Two Mouse Events on Single MouseUp

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling, mouseup

After reviewing the first 72 search results for "mouseup firing two events", I believe this maybe user-error issue on my part. The following is an abridged example of how the code is setup.

**HTML Page:**

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="FormButtonRow">
   <!-- ... somes stuff.. -->
   <button type="button" id="FormNextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#FormNextBtn").mouseup(function(e){
        FormButtonEvent(e, "Next");
    })
});

function FormButtonEvent(e,btnName){
    console.log(btnName);
}
```

As I was setting up this question, I may have found the problem, but I want your feedback so I can get a broader perspective on how this happens.

***Problem***
Is it that, when passing the event handling to a function from an anonymous function, event bubbling causes the mouseup to be called again?

Answer (score 0):

***What "solved" it***

What I did to test the event bubbling idea was to keep as much contained within the anonymous function attached to the JQuery mouseup() event. Unfortunately this **did not** halt the second event trigger.

What did solve it, was to go back to the basics of vanilla JavaScript. In attaching the function directly to the HTML element using the onmouseup attribute, the event fired only once as needed.